# How exactly does R parse `->`, the right-assignment operator?

Tags: r, yacc

So this is kind of a trivial question, but it's bugging me that I can't answer it, and perhaps the answer will teach me some more details about how R works.

The title says it all: how does R parse `->`, the obscure right-side assignment function?

My usual tricks to dive into this failed:

```
`->`
```

> Error: object `->` not found

```
getAnywhere("->")
```

> no object named `->` was found

And we can't call it directly:

```
`->`(3,x)
```

> Error: could not find function `"->"`

But of course, it works:

```
(3 -> x) #assigns the value 3 to the name x
# [1] 3
```

It appears R knows how to simply reverse the arguments, but I thought the above approaches would surely have cracked the case:

```
pryr::ast(3 -> y)
# \- ()
#   \- `<- #R interpreter clearly flipped things around
#   \- `y  #  (by the time it gets to `ast`, at least...)
#   \-  3  #  (note: this is because `substitute(3 -> y)` 
#          #   already returns the reversed version)
```

Compare this to the regular assignment operator:

```
`<-`
.Primitive("<-")

`<-`(x, 3) #assigns the value 3 to the name x, as expected
```

`?"->"` , `?assignOps`, and the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) all simply mention it in passing as the right assignment operator.

But there's clearly something unique about how `->` is used. It's not a function/operator (as the calls to `getAnywhere` and directly to `` `->` `` seem to demonstrate), so what is it? Is it completely in a class of its own?

Is there anything to learn from this besides "`->` is completely unique within the R language in how it's interpreted and handled; memorize and move on"?

Comment: Actually this linked related question is much more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309687/parsing-assignment-operator-in-r

Comment: You simply setting a label a value. This does not mean that they are identically

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying I know absolutely nothing about how parsers work. Having said that, [line 296 of gram.y](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/main/gram.y#L296) defines the following tokens to represent assignment in the (YACC?) parser R uses:

```
%token      LEFT_ASSIGN EQ_ASSIGN RIGHT_ASSIGN LBB
```

Then, [on lines 5140 through 5150 of gram.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/main/gram.c##L5140-L5150), this looks like the corresponding C code:

```c
case '-':
  if (nextchar('>')) {
    if (nextchar('>')) {
      yylval = install_and_save2("<<-", "->>");
      return RIGHT_ASSIGN;
    }
    else {
      yylval = install_and_save2("<-", "->");
      return RIGHT_ASSIGN;
    }
  }
```

Finally, starting on [line 5044 of gram.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/main/gram.c#L5044), the definition of `install_and_save2`:

```c
/* Get an R symbol, and set different yytext.  Used for translation of -> to <-. ->> to <<- */
static SEXP install_and_save2(char * text, char * savetext)
{
    strcpy(yytext, savetext);
    return install(text);
}
```

---

So again, having zero experience working with parsers, it seems that `->` and `->>` are translated directly into `<-` and `<<-`, respectively, at a *very low level* in the interpretation process.

---

You brought up a very good point in asking how the parser "knows" to reverse the arguments to `->` - considering that `->` appears to be installed into the R symbol table as `<-` - and thus be able to correctly interpret `x -> y` as `y <- x` and *not* `x <- y`. The best I can do is provide further speculation as I continue to come across "evidence" to support my claims. Hopefully some merciful YACC expert will stumble on this question and provide a little insight; I'm not going to hold my breath on that, though.

Back to [lines 383 and 384 of gram.y](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/main/gram.y#L383-L384), this looks like some more parsing logic related to the aforementioned `LEFT_ASSIGN` and `RIGHT_ASSIGN` symbols:

```
|   expr LEFT_ASSIGN expr       { $$ = xxbinary($2,$1,$3);  setId( $$, @$); }
|   expr RIGHT_ASSIGN expr      { $$ = xxbinary($2,$3,$1);  setId( $$, @$); }
```

Although I can't really make heads or tails of this crazy syntax, I did notice that the second and third arguments to `xxbinary` are swapped to WRT `LEFT_ASSIGN` (`xxbinary($2,$1,$3)`) and `RIGHT_ASSIGN` (`xxbinary($2,$3,$1)`).

Here's what I'm picturing in my head:

`LEFT_ASSIGN` Scenario:  `y <- x`

- `$2` is the second "argument" to the parser in the above expression, i.e. `<-`
- `$1` is the first; namely `y`
- `$3` is the third; `x`

Therefore, the resulting (C?) call would be `xxbinary(<-, y, x)`.

Applying this logic to `RIGHT_ASSIGN`, i.e. `x -> y`, combined with my earlier conjecture about `<-` and `->` getting swapped,

- `$2` gets translated from `->` to `<-`
- `$1` is `x`
- `$3` is `y`

But since the result is `xxbinary($2,$3,$1)` instead of `xxbinary($2,$1,$3)`, the result is *still* `xxbinary(<-, y, x)`.

---

Building off of this a little further, we have the definition of `xxbinary` on [line 3310 of gram.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/main/gram.c#L3310):

```c
static SEXP xxbinary(SEXP n1, SEXP n2, SEXP n3)
{
    SEXP ans;
    if (GenerateCode)
    PROTECT(ans = lang3(n1, n2, n3));
    else
    PROTECT(ans = R_NilValue);
    UNPROTECT_PTR(n2);
    UNPROTECT_PTR(n3);
    return ans;
}
```

Unfortunately I could not find a proper definition of `lang3` (or its variants `lang1`, `lang2`, etc...) in the R source code, but I'm assuming that it is used for evaluating special functions (i.e. symbols) in a way that is synchronized with the interpreter.

---

**Updates** 
I'll try to address some of your additional questions in the comments as best I can given my (very) limited knowledge of the parsing process.

> 1) Is this really the only object in R that behaves like this?? (I've
>   got in mind the John Chambers quote via Hadley's book: "Everything
>   that exists is an object. Everything that happens is a function call."
>   This clearly lies outside that domain -- is there anything else like
>   this?

First, I agree that this lies outside of that domain. I believe Chambers' quote concerns the R Environment, i.e. processes that are all taking place after this low level parsing phase. I'll touch on this a little bit more below, however. Anyways, the only other example of this sort of behavior I could find is the `**` operator, which is a synonym for the more common exponentiation operator `^`. As with right assignment, `**` doesn't seem to be "recognized" as a function call, etc... by the interpreter:

```r
R> `->`
#Error: object '->' not found
R> `**`
#Error: object '**' not found
```

I found this because it's the only other case where `install_and_save2` [is used by the C parser](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/main/gram.c##L5230-L5241):

```c
case '*':
  /* Replace ** by ^.  This has been here since 1998, but is
     undocumented (at least in the obvious places).  It is in
     the index of the Blue Book with a reference to p. 431, the
     help for 'Deprecated'.  S-PLUS 6.2 still allowed this, so
     presumably it was for compatibility with S. */
  if (nextchar('*')) {
    yylval = install_and_save2("^", "**");
    return '^';
  } else
    yylval = install_and_save("*");
return c;
```

---

> 2) When exactly does this happen? I've got in mind that substitute(3
>   -> y) has already flipped the expression; I couldn't figure out from the source what substitute does that would have pinged the YACC...

Of course I'm still speculating here, but yes, I think we can safely assume that when you call `substitute(3 -> y)`, from the perspective of [the substitute function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/main/coerce.c##L2599-L2631), the expression *always was* `y <- 3`; e.g. the function is completely unaware that you typed `3 -> y`. `do_substitute`, like 99% of the C functions used by R, only handles `SEXP` arguments - an `EXPRSXP` in the case of `3 -> y` (== `y <- 3`), I believe. This is what I was alluding to above when I made a distinction between the R Environment and the parsing process. I don't think there is anything that specifically triggers the parser to spring into action - but rather **everything** you input into the interpreter gets parsed. I did a *little* more reading about the YACC / Bison parser *generator* last night, and as I understand it (a.k.a. don't bet the farm on this), Bison uses the grammar you define (in the `.y` file(s)) to *generate* a parser in C - i.e. a C function which does the actual parsing of input. In turn, everything you input in an R session is first processed by this C parsing function, which then delegates the appropriate action to be taken in the R Environment (I'm using this term very loosely by the way). During this phase, `lhs -> rhs` will get translated to `rhs <- lhs`, `**` to `^`, etc... For example, this is an excerpt from one of the [tables of primitive functions in names.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7c99565e57967caaa0e454f7cb62c111d046b265/src/main/names.c##L89-L104):

```c
/* Language Related Constructs */

/* Primitives */
{"if",      do_if,      0,  200,    -1, {PP_IF,      PREC_FN,     1}},
{"while",   do_while,   0,  100,    2,  {PP_WHILE,   PREC_FN,     0}},
{"for",     do_for,     0,  100,    3,  {PP_FOR,     PREC_FN,     0}},
{"repeat",  do_repeat,  0,  100,    1,  {PP_REPEAT,  PREC_FN,     0}},
{"break",   do_break, CTXT_BREAK,   0,  0,  {PP_BREAK,   PREC_FN,     0}},
{"next",    do_break, CTXT_NEXT,    0,  0,  {PP_NEXT,    PREC_FN,     0}},
{"return",  do_return,  0,  0,  -1, {PP_RETURN,  PREC_FN,     0}},
{"function",    do_function,    0,  0,  -1, {PP_FUNCTION,PREC_FN,     0}},
{"<-",      do_set,     1,  100,    -1, {PP_ASSIGN,  PREC_LEFT,   1}},
{"=",       do_set,     3,  100,    -1, {PP_ASSIGN,  PREC_EQ,     1}},
{"<<-",     do_set,     2,  100,    -1, {PP_ASSIGN2, PREC_LEFT,   1}},
{"{",       do_begin,   0,  200,    -1, {PP_CURLY,   PREC_FN,     0}},
{"(",       do_paren,   0,  1,  1,  {PP_PAREN,   PREC_FN,     0}},
```

You will notice that `->`, `->>`, and `**` are not defined here. As far as I know, R primitive expressions such as `<-` and `[`, etc... are the closest interaction the R Environment ever has with any underlying C code. What I am suggesting is that by this stage in process (from you typing a set characters into the interpreter and hitting 'Enter', up through the actual evaluation of a valid R expression), the parser has already worked its magic, which is why you can't get a function definition for `->` or `**` by surrounding them with backticks, as you typically can.

Comment: in the meantime dare i say this answer is worth of a `gram.y`? ok i should seriously get back to work...

Comment: Just for the record (and also as a complete parser newbie) I'll note that it appears that there's [a distinction](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.1) between a token's type (here `RIGHT_ASSIGN`) and its value (here `<-`, assigned to `yylval` by `install_and_save2`). It appears to me that the **type** gets used to direct the expression's parsing (sending us down the branch that reads `{ $$ = xxbinary($2,$3,$1);  setId( $$, @$); }`), while it's **value** is what gets passed on through `xxbinary`'s first argument (i.e. the `$2`).

Comment: @Josh O'Brien Thank you for the input (and the edits as well); on the surface that sounds reasonable to me. If you are up for it at some point, please feel free to add that or any other relevant information to my answer (I'm afraid I would butcher the explanation if I tried to phrase that myself).

Comment: @nrussell You're welcome. `lang3` et al. are inlined functions, and are found [here, in `$RHOME/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h#L300-L319). Looks to me like their role here is to glom together the individual tokens and parsed expressions into list-like language objects, building up towards a completely parsed version of the inputted expression.

Comment: thanks for the update! as to `**`, i _do_ remember at least reading at some point somewhere that that operator is sort of vestigal, so at least i've seen it recognized as sort of an outcast before. anyway, my utility built is now full of questionably-useful knowledge... just how i like it!