# Quotations marks and expression

Tags: r

I've started today studying the R language.

After defining two vectors `x,y` i applied the outer product between them, applying what the documentation says.

```
f= outer (x, y, FUN = "*")
```

And all went great.
Then i decide to try an anonymous function, so i wrote

```
f= outer (x, y, FUN = "function(x,y) cos(y) / (1+x^2)")
```

But i got an error. However if i write:

```
`f= outer (x, y, FUN = function(x,y) cos(y) / (1+x^2))`
```

It works.

Why the quotations marks work with * but not with this anonymous function ?
Thanks for your time

Comment: because you have used variables, putting them in quotes doesn't tell R that it's a variable

Comment: try `a = 1; b =2` and then do `"a + b"` and `a + b`. It's the same reason.

Comment: But why with the * works ?

Comment: Read the documentation at `?outer` and `?match.fun`

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by this code "working":

```
`f= outer (x, y, FUN = function(x,y) cos(y) / (1+x^2))`
```

What this will do is attempt to access a *variable* named `f= outer (x, y, FUN = function(x,y) cos(y) / (1+x^2))`, e.g. I could write:

```
`f= outer (x, y, FUN = function(x,y) cos(y) / (1+x^2))` = 3
`f= outer (x, y, FUN = function(x,y) cos(y) / (1+x^2))`
# [1] 3
```

This is an insanely confusing thing to do, but surrounding objects in backticks (`` ` ``) allows you to declare arbitrarily-named objects.

Again, don't do this unless you absolutely know what you're doing (i.e. well past your first day of R programming).

Anyway, regarding why `*` needs quotation marks, it's because *`*` is an **operator***. [Everything in R is a function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) ([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599027/how-exactly-does-r-parse-the-right-assignment-operator)), but operators are special functions in that they let you write them from left to right like:

```
variable1 operator variable2
```

instead of the normal

```
function(variable1, variable2)
```

That said, all operators *also* have a *functional* form; but, to distinguish the functional form from the operator form, the R parser needs them to be set apart with quotes (or with backticks); the following are the same:

```
3 * 4
'*'(3, 4)
"*"(3, 4) #single and double quotes in R are basically the same
`*`(3, 4)
```

the `FUN` argument of `outer` requires *functions*, not *operators*, so we have to serve `*` in its *functional* form, e.g. `"*"`.

One more bit of detail -- you can observe R internally changing the operator form into the functional form as part of the code-parsing process (i.e., before evaluation, R will already convert the operator form into functional form):

```
as.character(substitute(3 * 4))
# [1] "*" "3" "4"

# alternatively
pryr::ast(3 * 4)
# \- ()
#   \- `*
#   \-  3
#   \-  4
```